# File keeps reloading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem(or some inconvenience)

I have made my own webpage on chrome.  It's suppose to be a quiz with ten questions.  The quiz isn't complete yet, but right now that isn't the issue.  The issue is that for some reason every time I click the button near the end of the page, the page refreshes.  I don't want the page to refresh when I click the button.  Any tips?  Here is my html file.  Run the codes in your browsers if you need to understand what I am asking.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="quiz" content="myown quiz">
    <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="machine.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizformatting.css">
    <h1>Choose the major right for you</h1>
    <pre>
    <form>
    Do you like enjoy programming?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="program">Yes</option>
    <option class="no">No</option>
    </select>

    Do you enjoy 2d animation and 3d animation?
     <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="art">Yes</option>
    <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>

     Do you like music
     <select>
     <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option class="no">no</option>
     </select>

    What are your favorite pastimes?
    <select>
     <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Listening to music</option>
     <option class="program">making websites</option>
     <option class="art">Drawing</option>
    <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>

    Out of all the activities you like to do, which one do you enjoy the most?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="art">Painting and drawing</option>
    <option class="music">Playing instruments</option>
    <option class="art">Drawing</option>
    <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>

    Would you be interested in making art or coding for video games?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
     <option class="program">I would be interested in learning the programming 
    languages used to create the scripting for games</option>
     <option class="art">I would like to the models and the environment for 
    modeling</option>
    <option class="no">I'm not interested in either of these options</option>
    </select>

    Do you enjoy making websites or learning how to sing?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Learning how to sing</option>
    <option class="program">making websites for projects</option>
    <option class="no">I'm not interested in any of this</option>
    </select>

    Do you enjoy listening to music more or making programming applications?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">I would like to listen to music</option>
    <option class="program">Programming is my thing</option>
    <option class="art">I'm more of a drawer</option>
    <option class="no">I don't like any of these options</option>
    </select>

    Which skillset are you more interested in learning?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Learning the notes of instruments</option>
    <option class="program">Learning the language of javascript</option>
    <option class="art">I like anime, so I would love to learn how to animate in 
    anime style</option>
     <option class="no">I don't want to do any of these options</option>
    </select>

    Please press the button to get your answer

    <button onclick="Starting();">Click me</button>
    </form>
    </pre>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my Stylesheet file.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}

button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is my javascript file:(To clarify, right now that isn't what I'm concerned about right now)

```
function Starting() {

    var artchoices = document.querySelectorAll(".art");
    var program = document.querySelectorAll(".program");
    var choice = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
    var no = document.querySelectorAll(".no:checked");
    var music = document.querySelectorAll(".music");

    let answer = true;

    for (var e = 0; e < choice.length; e++) {

        if (choice[e].selected == true) {
            answer = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (answer = false) {
        console.log("Make sure you checked all values");

    } else {
        if (no = 9) {
            console.log("Oh, so you don't want to become anything huh");

        } else {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, it's rarely suitable for an `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to have a type, and set that type to button like so

```
<button type="button" onclick="Starting()">Click Me</button>
```

Because you have wrapped all of your select inputs inside of a form element, your button is acting as a submit button by default that automatically submits the form when you click it, which causes the page refresh that you are experiencing. The solution would be to either get rid of the form element if you don't need to wrap your select buttons in a form, or simply change your button type to be "button" which makes it not submit the form when you click it and act as a standalone button.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to prevent the default behavior of the button. 
This can be done easily with the preventDefault() function.

```
function Starting(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: To add on to this. You're not necessarily stopping the default behavior of the button itself, but the actual event taking place. Whenever an event triggers a javascript function, it passes in that event as the first parameter. By using the preventDefault() method of the event, you are preventing the event from doing it's default behavior. In this case the event taking place is onSubmit, as the button is submitting the form.

Comment: Aviv Biton where do I put this starting(event) function?  Anywhere?